# Dart: How to add elements to a Map inherited from parent class

Tags: dart

I have a class with a Map:

```dart
class A {
   Map<String,String> get data => { "index1": "value1" };
   // other methods and props
}
```

And I need to have a class B that extends it, and adds new elements to the map. For example, I want to have in B instances both index1 and index2 in the map:

```
class B extends A {
   @override
   Map<String,String> get data => { ...data, "index2": "value2"}
}
```

But the spread operator is for lists... also I dont' know if I can access `data` in the child like this.
Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spread operator can be used for maps also.
In order to access member of parent class you should use super:

```
super.data
```

Like this:

```dart
class B extends A {
   @override
   Map<String,String> get data => { ... super.data, "index2": "value2"};
}
```